# java swing contentPane.remove remove the panels but graphics stay on screen

Tags: java

so I have this perfectly normal code 
the thing is that these elemnts get removed from the panel (logically) but the graphics stay for example the button stop interacting it just freez there . 
and when I pass a jlabel above (I have drag and drop jlabel) these elements they get wiped.

[image]

```
 contentPane.remove(Quitter); 
 contentPane.remove( PanelInit);
```

Anyone here have an idea how to fix it ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: You need to call `contentPane.revalidate();` followed by `contentPane.repaint();` after removing or adding components. But better still -- use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to help you swap components.

Comment: Another question -- are you overriding paint or paintComponent? And if so, are you appropriately calling the super's painting method in your own override?

Comment: And if you're still stuck after checking the duplicates, then consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or [mre] where you condense your code into the smallest bit (small enough to post as code-formatted text in your question) that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

using the repaint function fixed the whole thing . 
hope this help anyone in the future.
     contentPane.repaint();